# Supported oracle versions with Nhibernate 2.1..2

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I have a question, and I would really appreciate your advice or a link to any official document related to it. My question is: Which Oracle Versions are supported by Nhibernate version 2.1.2?

In a nutshell, we have a system using Nhibernate 2.1.2 with Oracle 10g. We are interested in migrating to Oracle 11x, or even Oracle 12x ("x" is for any sub versions). The problem is that all database transactions are handled by Nhibernate, and we have not been able to find any official information about supported third-party software.

This is a critical challenge, as the current error log of this system is plaged with errors like "Exception while updating RequestLog2::Unexpected row count: 0 expected 1" thrown by Nhibernate.AdoNet.Expectations.BasicExpecation.VerifyOutcomeNonBatched. The conclusion after a year of research was that this cannot be fixed, which kind of upsetted the Management Team. More over, we have some deadlocks, about once per week, also unfixable. The list continues, but the system, as a whole, works. For that and many more reasons, the Management Team is a little bit nervous about migrating to an unsuported version of Oracle, and then finding themselves with a system with more of these errors.

Thank you very much for any information you can share about this question!

Best Regards,

Tarh Ik

Answer (score 0):

On [NHibernate's Github page](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/2.1.x/src/NHibernate/Dialect) you can see a list of dialects that NHibernate suppports. Here are the oracle ones listed:

- Oracle10gDialect
- Oracle8iDialect
- Oracle9iDialect
- OracleLiteDialect

Now, it depends on what you mean by *support*.

- If you mean *support with full support for newer Oracle functionality and built-in functions*, then no, even NHibernate 4.0.x doesn't ship with a dialect specific to Oracle 11 or 12.
- If you mean *just work ok*, then I would think that using the Oracle 10g dialect with Oracle 11 or 12 would work fine--just based on the assumption that newer versions of database engines are backwards-compatible with code written for Oracle 10.

All that said I don't know anything about Oracle and I can't say for sure if upgrading will go smoothly. The best thing to do is try it out.

No matter what though, without creating your own dialect for the newer version of Oracle (which by the way is not that hard), there's no built-in support for the newer versions of Oracle except via the older Oracle dialects.